# Signing android apk

Tags: android, apk

I know there are already so many questions asked on this topic. I do have a look on them.But didn't find solution to my problem:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore myCertificate.keystore 
 -alias mykey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000

 But it shows following error:

 keytool error: java.io.filenotfound exception: myCertificate.keystore (access is denied)
```

Comment: before this step..i only created a apk unsigned file of project and then this..i don't think i miss something..do i!!!!!!

Comment: are you using windows, i have to run the console as administrator, right click console and run as administrator maybe?

Comment: Did you validate that the password for the key were the same and proper?

Answer (score 0):

Run CMD as Administrator... Hope you get rid from permission error.